# Get System Manufacturer and Model in Python

Tags: python, operating-system

I've been trying to get the current system manufacturer in python. I have seen ways to do it in windows using the wmi module for windows. But how to get it in Linux and Mac?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that I understand the specific thing you are talking about, but I **can** tell you what command gets name of OS, etc.

---

**NOTE: These all include the `platform` library.**

---

- Get OS Name: `my_os = platform.system()`
- Get the system's release version: `release = platform.release()`
- Get the OS, version, etc. together: `data = platform.platform()`
- Get Processor: `processor = platform.processor()`
- Get Architecture: `architecture = platform.architecture()`
- Get Machine Type: `machinetype = platform.machine()`

---

That's all I know, and I hope this will work.